# How can I use methodes from .py file in py-script html tag

Tags: python, html, pyscript

I use  tag in html to use methodes from a .py file in .html page ,
so I start with this in html body:

```
<py-env>
    - paths:
        - ./methodes.py
</py-env>
```

then i use the methode getEmoji(string) :

```
    <py-script>
        from methodes import *
        text = "ubio gfsh"
        print(justFr(text))
    </py-script>
```

my page .html and the file methodes.py in same folder , and i get this message :

```
JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 421, in eval_code CodeRunner( File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 237, in __init__ self.ast = next(self._gen) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 141, in _parse_and_compile_gen mod = compile(source, filename, mode, flags | ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST) File "", line 2 text = "ubio gfsh" ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent )
```

any help Please ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use Python indenting otherwise the Python interpreter will report the error **IndentationError: unexpected indent**.

Delete the spaces in front of each Python code line:

```
<py-script>
from methodes import *
text = "ubio gfsh"
print(justFr(text))
</py-script>
```

Only indent lines when Python requires it.